# 110% height vs 100% scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css

Okay so i couldn't find an answer to this on the web.

Basically, if i set my body to, lets say max-height-8000px.

and i have a div that is nested within body and i set it to have a height of 150%;

logically, thats 12000px for the inner div.

people are only able to see whats in the body, does this mean that when a user scrolls 100% of the page, will the scroll distance be 8000 or 12000.

The reason im asking is because i'm using javascript that triggers events at scroll percentages, and im curious as to what would happen if a person scrolled 100% on a div that is 150% height of its parent.
or what would i be able to trigger events at 110% or even 150%?

Comment: wasn't this something that you could simply try and run? If you don't have a local machine setup currently then you could try jsfiddle.net . i just tried it there and it seems the 150% div will let you scroll to 12kpx

Answer (score 0):

First of all you cant leave body just with a max-height: 8000px; Because its height remains 0px so the inner will have 150% of 0px = 0px. So you need to add height: 800px to body. And when a user scrolls 100% of the page, scroll distance will be 12000. Hope this helps you.